# Line chart with fixed y-axis?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to have a line chart with a fixed y-axis. that is, I have values that are mostly between 30 and 70, but I'd like to have the chart y-axis as a constant between 0 and 100 so it wouldn't resize as new values are coming in (if they happen to be larger than previous values).

How'd I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Set minimum and maximum properties of LinearAxis. Something like this:

```
<mx:verticalAxis>
<mx:LinearAxis  title="title" displayName="displayName" maximum="100" minimum="0"/>
</mx:verticalAxis>
```

Answer (score 0):

And don't you want to give a try to existing classes? :)

**Yahoo's Astra pack**
http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/charts/using.html

Or you may post some sample code so we can see what should be modified.